# How do I create a full memory dump to a remote machine?

Tags: debugging, kernel, windbg, crash-dumps

I want to take a full physical memory dump of a remote machine.

What is the easiest way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with WinDbg. It seems you already know WinDbg, since you used the tag. Establish a [remote kernel session (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439346(v=vs.85).aspx).

Once connected, use `.dump /f` to take a full kernel dump, which is the contents of the physical RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the Windows flavor, but in general like this (Windows 7 example):

1. Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced -> Startup and recovery -> settings. In the write debugging information listbox select full memory dump and write the path for storage.
   Select automatically restart checkbox as well.
2. Create a task to be run at system startup (run Task Scheduler utility) that will take the memory dump file and copy it to the prefered remote location. The task can be a simple script in any supported scripting language (most straightforward is to use to use that Windows batch language).

Comment: What if I want to create a live memory dump. ie, do not want to restart the cpmputer?

Comment: There is no such thing as live memory dump. You can connect a debugger to your computer that will break upon error instead of causing a BSOD.

Comment: How about livekd.exe with .dump /f c:\out.dmp ? I just wonder if I can to this remotely without using psexec.

Comment: You can create a memory dump while debugging live but unless you bring your system to the point of failure, what would be the point of such memory dump? And if you bring it to the failure point, you'll need to restart it to continue working. Regarding using `livekd`, I don't quite understand what you're trying to do - do you want to copy the memory dump from local machine to remote, or get the dump from remote machine?

Comment: I want to get dump from remote machine. Lets say it's deadlocked between processes, or does not come to the point of an obvious failure that might cause a crash dump action to be triggered. Or lets say i'm creating a dump of a virtual machine for forensics purposes.

Comment: `livekd` seems legit for this purpose. You need to somehow identify when to get the memory dump. Invoking `livekd` via `psexec` or similar tool seems the natural thing to do. You can also rely on some more complex mechanism - e.g., the remote system can monitor whether some event has occurred in a predefined time limit and if not, trigger locally the memory dump collection.

Comment: @prgDevelop wouldn't it be more appropriate to just take dumps of the involved processes?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: if there are Mutexes involved in a deadlock between processes, could that still be debugged with 2 user mode dumps only?